# Creating Cassandra schema

Tags: cassandra

I wrote brief schema for my project.
I am a beginner of Cassandra.
The schema looks like this.

```
User = { uid: “”,
         media{ 
           media1:{
                     Rating:”” ,
                     Views:””,
                     Like:””
            },
        media2:{
        },
        media3:{
        },
        ……
         }
 }



Media={ mediaId:{
    user:{ 
        user1: {

                         rating:”” ,
                             views :””,
                             like:”” ,
                             comment:””
         },

        user2:{
                },
        user3:{
                },
        …..
        },

        category:””,
            views:””,
            rating:””,
            likes:””,
            attributes:{
             audio:{
                             albumimgurl:””
                                 track:””,
                                 artist:””,
                                 duration:””,
                                 url:””
            },
            image:{

                    smallurl:””,
                    largeurl:””,
                    title:””
           },
           video:{
                  coverimage:””,
                  url:””,
                  duration:””,
                  title:””
           },

           article:{
             title:””,
                             content:””
           },
       wallpaper:{
                     title:””,
                     smallurl:””,
                     midurl:””,
                     largeurl:””
        },
       },
  }
```

First I have no idea my schema is right for Cassandra.
Please tell me that the schema is right for Cassandra.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with JSON model is fine, since is easy to read - not in your case, but in general ;)

Here is nice formatter: http://jsonlint.com/

One level in JSON document corresponds to Column Family, two levels are representing already Super Column Family, and those are deprecated. More levels is not possible. When you need more levels use compound keys.

To remove one level from your JSON document:

```
attributes:{
             audio:{
                             albumimgurl:””
                                 track:””,
                                 artist:””,
                                 duration:””,
                                 url:””
```

change it to:

```
attributes:{
             audio:albumimgurl:””
             audio:track:””,
             audio:artist:””,
             audio:duration:””,
             audio:url:””
```

where `audio:albumimgurl` is column name - this in Cassandra Compound Column.

You can use any number of compounds, so: `attributes:audio:albumimgurl` is fine too